# How to import "dat" file including only certain strings in python

Tags: python, python-import, spyder

I am trying to import several "dat" files to python spyder.

[dat_file_list_images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JCNb.png)

Here are dat files listed, and there are two types on the list ended with _1 and _2. I wanna import dat files ended with "_1" only.

Is there any way to import them at once with one single loop?

After I import them, I would like to aggregate all to one single matrix.

Comment: use string slicing to check if it ends with a '1' before performing your operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

files_to_import = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path)
                  if f.endswith("1")]
```

Make sure that you know whether the files have a .dat-extension or not - in Windows Explorer, the default setting is to hide file endings, and this will make your code fail if the files have a different ending.

What this code does is called list comprehension - os.listdir() provides all the files in the folder, and you create a list with only the ones that end with "1".

Answer (score 0):

Uses str.endswith() it will return true if the entered string is ended with checking string

According to this [website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_endswith.htm)

Syntax: `str.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]])`

For your case:

You will need a loop to get filenames as String and check it while looping if it ends with "_1"

```py
yourFilename = "yourfilename_1"
if yourFilename.endswith("_1"):
  # do your job here
```

Comment: Thanks for your help... unfortunately I had to choose one.